# I am unable to ignore the failed response code/message using BeanShell PostProcessor in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing, beanshell, jsr223

I am having multiple sampler in which i am trying to setup a script which ignores an error message or any response code and tryinh to make a sampler as "pass".

but i am unable to do that.

Below is my configuration.

[JMeter Configuration for BeanShell Post Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il0pI.png)

You can see that in an benshell postprocessor i tries to ignore 3 responses (non http , 504 and 401)

But in the "View Result Tree" listner i am still getting ignored status code as failed.

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWEil.png)

You can see in an image that 401 error code request is failed.

Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

I also tried jsr223 response assertion,but not able to get expected output.

I also checked my logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your script:

1. You're using `==` instead of [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) which compares references and not instances so it might be the case the code is not executed at all
2. Setting response code to `200` is not sufficient to suppress the failure, you need to additionally invoke [`prev.setSuccessful(true)`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSuccessful(boolean)) function
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) because [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)
4. You might want to use [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement instead of multiple if/else clauses

Answer (score -3):

Hello why you use JMeter do you know K6 : https://k6.io/
It's better than JMeter